# Overloading the << operator for a toString function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Im trying to overload my output operator, <<.  I feel as if I'm very close but I am getting a cannot bind error. Below, I have my Operators.cpp class, my graphcode.h and my main.cpp where I'm trying to overload the toString function.

```
 #include "GraphCode.h"
    #include "Node.h"


    /****************************************************************
     * Overloaded '<<' operator
    **/
    ofstream& operator <<(ofstream &outStream, const GraphCode& graphCode)
    {
      outStream << graphCode.toString();
      return outputStream;
    }
    //*******************************************************************

    #ifndef GRAPHCODE_H
    #define GRAPHCODE_H

    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    using namespace std;

    #include "../../Utilities/Utils.h"
    #include "../../Utilities/Scanner.h"
    #include "../../Utilities/ScanLine.h"

    #include "Node.h"
    #include "MyRandom.h"

    class GraphCode
    {
    public:
      GraphCode();
      virtual ~GraphCode();

      void createGraph(Scanner& inStream); // not used in this assignment
      void descendFrom(ofstream& outStream, string blanks, Node& node); // recursive function
      void doSearch(ofstream& outStream); // top level of recursive search function
      void readGraph(Scanner& inStream); // to read a graph (instead of creating one)
      string toString();

      friend ofstream& operator <<(ofstream& outStream, const GraphCode& graphCode); 

    private:
      vector<string> path;
      vector<Node> theGraph;

      // the 'blanks' is the leading string of blanks so that recursion levels can be seen
      string toStringChildren(string blanks, const vector<int>& children);
      string toStringPath(string blanks);
    };

    #endif

//***************************************************************

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
      string inFileName = "";
      string outFileName = "";
      string logFileName = "";
      ofstream outStream;

      Scanner inStream;

      GraphCode graphCode;

      Utils::CheckArgs(3, argc, argv, "infilename outfilename logfilename");

      inFileName = static_cast<string>(argv[1]); // DO NOT USE OLD CAST!
      outFileName = static_cast<string>(argv[2]);
      logFileName = static_cast<string>(argv[3]);

      Utils::LogFileOpen(logFileName);

      Utils::logStream << "Beginning execution\n";
      Utils::logStream.flush();

      Utils::FileOpen(outStream, outFileName);

      Utils::logStream << "infile  '" << inFileName << "'\n";
      Utils::logStream << "outfile '" << outFileName << "'\n";
      Utils::logStream << "logfile '" << logFileName << "'\n";

      inStream.openFile(inFileName);
    //  graphCode.createGraph(inStream);
      graphCode.readGraph(inStream);
      inStream.close();

      outStream << "RAW GRAPH\n" << graphCode << endl; //changed from  //graphCode.toString()

      outStream.flush();

      outStream << "SEARCH\n";
      graphCode.doSearch(outStream);
      outStream.flush();

      Utils::FileClose(outStream);

      Utils::logStream << "Ending execution\n";
      Utils::logStream.flush();

      Utils::FileClose(Utils::logStream);

      return 0;
    }

//Main.cpp:48:13: error: cannot bind ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ lvalue to //‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’
  // outStream << "RAW GRAPH\n" << graphCode << endl; //this line was //changed.....  ^

//In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39:0,
//                 from Main.h:13,
//                 from Main.cpp:1:
///usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:602:5: error:   initializing argument 1 of //‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& //std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with //_CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Tp = GraphCode]’
//     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
//     ^
```

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: i will update with a comment at bottom of my code

Comment: if anyway you implement a `toString()` you could aswell provide a string conversion operator, then you do not need to overload the `<<` anymore (which is anyway just calling `toString()´).

Comment: edit was made to bottom of code

Comment: Do not overload the operator for `ofstream`, but for `ostream` (operations on streams return that)

Comment: yes i did make that change thank you but have you ever heard of this error:  Main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x347): undefined reference to `operator<<(std::ostream&, GraphCode const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Aprog] Error 1

Comment: Your undefined reference means that it found your declaration (presumably in the GraphCode declaration) and everything compiled but down it can't find the implementation to link.  Did you change it to ostream in both places?

Comment: yes i changed all instaces of ofstream to ostream, and im still receiving that error. never seen it before.  pretty sure my makefile is correct but if you think it could be there i can post it

Comment: Don't post your makefile.  Reduce your problem to something smaller then build back up.  Here is an example of your code reduced to the key components and it works (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e52781ceb5be9d40).  Build back up from there.

Comment: @JayMiller not quite true - `ofstream` inherits `ostream` so making the operator for `ostream` works as well but there is no reason why not to make the operator specific for `ofstream` (maybe he wants only file stream, not a generic one?)

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis While I wasn't actually the one to recommend switching to ostream, it is correct.  The call ```outStream << "RAW GRAPH\n"``` returns an ostream, not an ofstream, so the subsequent call of ```<< graphCode``` is a binary function with parameters ostream and GraphCode.

Comment: In fact having switched the OP no longer has a compiler error but a linker error.

Comment: @JayMiller true to that, since the operator is inherited the return type is `std::ostream` so the signature was wrong as well.

Comment: I was able to fix it, thank you all. I'm unsure of what was wrong with the code, obviously changing the ofstream to ostream was significant. But I made my toString in my .h and graphcode.cpp be const instead of just regular functions, and it worked. No clue how but I appreciate it!